# Maven Clean Install - Access Denied Exception due to file being held by another process

Tags: java, maven

I have a pom file that looks to install a couple of plugins. MCI keeps crashing on one plugin with an access denied issue every time. What I have found is that if I take out the plugin that it crashes on and put that in it's own file, then run the original pom file it will pass. If I attempt to run the second pom file straight after it will fail BUT if I wait about 10 seconds and run it, it will pass.

So it seems that plugin that crashes cannot update the ear file due to it still being held onto by another process. This is a very strange issue which I have never seen before and only started happening in the last week.

Has anyone experienced this before? I don't remember changing anything on my system to cause this but it's possible I have.

Comment: Are you working on Windows?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes. What I can't understand is that I didn't have this issue last week. Yet now is happening on both my laptop and desktop computer. Even if I revert the code it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Typical windows issue. Close all your application and run your build from plain command line (console) and recheck...

Comment: I'm actually trying this on an admin console I should have pointed out. I don't run it throught the application.

Comment: Maybe a virus scanner is in the game...

Comment: No it's an issue with a plugin called truezip. It seems it doesn't wait for the previous process to finish with a file and attempts to copy while it is still in use. Going to try adding a delay.

Comment: Having a multi module build running with parallelization?

Comment: There's no parrelization going on. It appears this may be something to do with the antivirus we use. We've decided to bypass the issue for now until we can find a solution at some point in the future! Thank you for your suggestions.